# GWT data display

Tags: java, gwt

As a means to display information on a website developed mainly with GWT and EXT-GWT, i am using a HTMLLayoutContainer. So far, the information it is displayed correctly, but it is too harsh or rough to display this way, meaning rough, not nice to see.

So the question is : Is there any other and nicer way to display (print, draw) information with GWT?.

If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work on CSS
[GWT CSS Ref](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html)